# Mercurial, how to get all modified/added file in specified branch and by specified use?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

How can I get list of files that were affected by specific user in the specified branch?

Regards, Evgeniy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gets you a list of all files modified by user X on branch Y:

```
hg log --branch Y --user X --template '{join(files, "\n")}\n'
```

but it will have duplicate entries for files modified, added, or removed in multiple changesets on that branch.  To consolidate them (on a unix-like you'd do):

```
hg log --branch Y --user X --template '{join(files, "\n")}\n'| sort -u
```

**Update**

If your Mercurial is to old for that fancy template to work you can probably do the same with this (if you're on a unix-like):

```
hg log --branch Y --user X --template '{files}\n' | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u
```

Comment: I am getting such error when use your command: `** unknown exception encountered, please report by visiting
**  http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BugTracker
** Python 2.7.3 (default, Apr 10 2013, 06:20:15) [GCC 4.6.3]
** Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.0.2)
** Extensions loaded: graphlog, mq
Traceback (most recent call last):
`

Comment: That syntax requires a more current Mercurial, yours is 22 months old.  I'll tack on a version for older Mercurials versions, but consider upgrading.  Things keep getting better and backward compatibility is absolute.